# EntityFramework TransactionScope results in error if there's a call to asp.net security within its scope

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I want to wrap some Entity Framework db I/o within a TransactionScope. In general it's working fine. But: I have some case that are basically like this:

```
using (var tx=new TransactionScope())
{
  using (var cx=new MyDbcontext())
  {
    var myrecord=cx.somerecorord.find(someid);
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(username, "admin"))
      DoAdminThing(myrecord);
    else
      DoNonAdminThing(myrecord);
    cx.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

This blows up on Roles.IsUserInRole with "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."

It appears that it doesn't like to do the asp.net security db I/o within an EF TransactionScope. Is there any way around this?

I really really don't want to have to move the Roles stuff to before the transaction. That would require breaking functions that logically hang together into pieces.

Comment: Hmm could you check if there is an inner exception to the one you're getting? TransactionScope should work fine across multiple databases.